approximation with smooth function in Bochner spaces
$X$  Banach separable
using the following:
$u∈W^{1,p}(0,T;X)⇒(u*ρ_ε)→u$ in $L^p(0,T;X)$ and $(u'*ρ_ε)→u'$ in $L_{loc}^p(0,T;X)$
Prove that:
$C^∞ ([0,T];X)$ is dens in $W^{1,p} ((0,T);X)$
my idea follows a similar proof for the usual case. The basic idea is as follows:

reflect $u(t)$ to obtain a function in $W^{1,p} (R;X)$

Reflect $u(t)$ Two times to obtain $v∈W^{1,p}([-T,2T];X)$ now multiply by a smooth function with compact support $ϕ$; supp$ϕ⊂[-T/2;3T/4]$ and $ϕ(t)=1$ on $[0,T]$ to obtain $ϕv∈W^{1,p} ([-T,2T];X)$ and supp$(vϕ)⊂[-T/2;3T/4]$   extending this function to the real line we get $(vϕ)∈ W^{1,p} (R;X).$

Now we prove the following $u'=v'$ in $L^p ((0,T);X)$   a.e.

without going into details,  since the statement is in $L^p ((0,T);X)4 we can use density results establish for it ; namely that it is enough to show:
$∫_0^T⟨u'(t)-v'(t),φ(t)z⟩dt=0 ∀φ∈C^∞ (0,T)  ∀ z∈X^*$
this follows immediately since:
$∫_0^T(u'(t)-v'(t))φ(t)dt=-∫_0^T(u(t)-v(t))φ'(t)dt=0∀φ∈C^∞ (0,T)$
the same results holds true for $u'=(vϕ)'$ in $L^p ((0,T);X)$ since $(vϕ) (t)=u(t)  ∀ t∈[0,T]$

to prove density it is enough to find a convergent sequence.

the desired sequence is $u_n=v_n|_{(0,T)}$
let $ρ_n$ Be a family of mollifiers and define $v_n=(vϕ) *ρ_n∈C^∞ (R;X)$  we know that $v_n→(vϕ)$ in $W^{1,p} (R;X)$ and so  define the sequence $u_n=v_n|_{(0,T)}$ (the restriction) . This is the desired sequence
